# Vue router-view does not show children

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a VueRouter with two levels:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: AboutComponent
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'plans',
                    name: 'Plans',
                    component: PlansComponent
                },
     },
]
```

The `App.vue` file has the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <nav>
                <template v-for="route in routes">
                    <div>
                        <router-link class="router-link" :key="route.path" :to="route.path">
                            {{route.name}}
                        </router-link>
                        <div v-for="child in route.children">
                            <router-link class="router-link router-link-child" :key="child.path" :to="{path: route.path + '/' + child.path}">
                                {{child.name}}
                            </router-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

My problem is that the menu is rendered correctly, but clicking the child item, **the component which is rendered is its parent component**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show AboutComponent code? It should include ` <router-view></router-view>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal vue-router behavior : if you want the nested route to be rendered, you need to add a `<router-view />` inside AboutComponent.

Exemple here : https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/

The User component contains the `<router-view />`